# Trying to create REST API's with Kotlin only. (IDE - Android Studio) open for IntelliJ IDEA IDE as well

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I tried doing few of the coding. I'm stuck up in linking to the database and writing the base URL. Currently I've connected to Firebase to my app while creating API.
New method or some guidance with this are appreciated.

Following are my code with XML.

1. Data Class.

```
    data class Employee(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val position: String
    )
```

2. Employee Adapter class.

```
    class EmployeeAdapter(private val employees: List<Employee>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_employee, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val employee = employees[position]
            holder.bind(employee)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return employees.size
        }
    
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            private val nameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView)
            private val positionTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.positionTextView)
    
            fun bind(employee: Employee) {
                nameTextView.text = employee.name
                positionTextView.text = employee.position
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Main Activity

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        private lateinit var adapter: EmployeeAdapter
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            adapter = EmployeeAdapter(emptyList())
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    
            val employeeService = RetrofitInstance.employeeService
    
            // Get all employees
            val getAllEmployeesCall: Call<List<Employee>> = employeeService.getEmployees()
            getAllEmployeesCall.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Employee>> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<Employee>>,
                    response: Response<List<Employee>>
                ) {
                    val employees = response.body()
                    if (employees != null) {
                        adapter = EmployeeAdapter(employees)
                        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Employee>>, t: Throwable) {
                    handleFailure("Failed to retrieve employees")
                }
            })
    
            // Create a new employee
            val newEmployee = Employee(id = 1, name = "John Doe", position = "Developer")
            val createEmployeeCall: Call<Employee> = employeeService.createEmployee(newEmployee)
            createEmployeeCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Employee> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Employee>, response: Response<Employee>) {
                    val createdEmployee = response.body()
                    if (createdEmployee != null) {
                        handleSuccess("Employee created: ${createdEmployee.name}")
                    } else {
                        handleFailure("Failed to create employee")
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Employee>, t: Throwable) {
                    handleFailure("Failed to create employee")
                }
            })
    
            // Update an existing employee
            val updatedEmployee = Employee(id = 1, name = "John Doe", position = "Senior Developer")
            val updateEmployeeCall: Call<Employee> = employeeService.updateEmployee(1, updatedEmployee)
            updateEmployeeCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Employee> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Employee>, response: Response<Employee>) {
                    val updatedEmployee = response.body()
                    if (updatedEmployee != null) {
                        handleSuccess("Employee updated: ${updatedEmployee.name}")
                    } else {
                        handleFailure("Failed to update employee")
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Employee>, t: Throwable) {
                    handleFailure("Failed to update employee")
                }
            })
    
            // Get a specific employee
            val getEmployeeCall: Call<Employee> = employeeService.getEmployee(1)
            getEmployeeCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Employee> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Employee>, response: Response<Employee>) {
                    val specificEmployee = response.body()
                    if (specificEmployee != null) {
                        handleSuccess("Retrieved specific employee: ${specificEmployee.name}")
                    } else {
                        handleFailure("Failed to retrieve specific employee")
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Employee>, t: Throwable) {
                    handleFailure("Failed to retrieve specific employee")
                }
            })
    
            // Delete an employee
            val deleteEmployeeCall: Call<Void> = employeeService.deleteEmployee(1)
            deleteEmployeeCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>) {
                    handleSuccess("Employee deleted successfully")
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {
                    handleFailure("Failed to delete employee")
                }
            })
        }
    
        private fun handleFailure(message: String) {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    
        private fun handleSuccess(message: String) {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
    
    4. Interface
    interface EmployeeService {
        @GET("employees")
        fun getEmployees(): Call<List<Employee>>
    
        @GET("employees/{id}")
        fun getEmployee(@Path("id") id: Int): Call<Employee>
    
        @POST("employees")
        fun createEmployee(@Body employee: Employee): Call<Employee>
    
        @PUT("employees/{id}")
        fun updateEmployee(@Path("id") id: Int, @Body employee: Employee): Call<Employee>
    
        @DELETE("employees/{id}")
        fun deleteEmployee(@Path("id") id: Int): Call<Void>
    }
```

5. Object

```
    object RetrofitInstance {
        private const val BASE_URL = "https://your-api-base-url.com/"
    
        private val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
    
        private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    
        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    
        val employeeService: EmployeeService = retrofit.create(EmployeeService::class.java)
    }
```

In main activity XML I've used Recycler view and two text views in `item_employee` XML to have employee details.
Please suggest and provide some inputs on this.